# Python code to process CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting the CSV file updated on daily basis. Need to process and create new file based on the criteria - If New data then should be tagged as New against the row and if its an update to the existing data then should be tagged as Update. How to write a Python code to process and output in CSV file as follows based on the date.

### Day1 input data

```
empid,enmname,sal,datekey
1,cholan,100,8/14/2018
2,ram,200,8/14/2018
```

### Day2 input Data

```
empid,enmname,sal,datekey
1,cholan,100,8/14/2018
2,ram,200,8/14/2018
3,sundar,300,8/15/2018
2,raman,200,8/15/2018
```

### Output Data

```
status,empid,enmname,sal,datekey
new,3,sundar,300,8/15/2018
update,2,raman,200,8/15/2018
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Using datetime, you can know the current date time and you know the date from your CSV file. Keep a check on date and you are good to go.

Comment: import pandas
dataInput = pandas.read_csv('source.csv')
RecentData = dataInput[dataInput['datekey']==dataInput.datekey.max()] i tried to get extract the recent update using the above code using pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I'm feeling nice, so I'll give you some code. Try to learn from it.

---

To work with CSV files, we'll need the `csv` module:

```
import csv
```

First off, let's teach the computer how to open and parse a CSV file:

```
def parse(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return list(csv.DictReader(f))
```

`csv.DictReader` reads the first line of the `csv` file and uses it as the "names" of the columns. It then creates a dictionary for each subsequent row, where the keys are the column names.

That's all well and good, but we just want the last version with each key:

```
def parse(path):
    data = {}
    with open(path) as f:
        for row in csv.DictReader(f):
            data[row["empid"]] = row
    return data
```

Instead of just creating a list containing everything, this creates a dictionary where the keys are the row's id. This way, rows found later in the file will overwrite rows found earlier in the file.

Now that we've taught the computer how to extract the data from the files, let's get it:

```
old_data = parse("file1.csv")
new_data = parse("file2.csv")
```

Iterating through a dictionary gives you its keys, which are the ids defined in the data set. For consistency, `key in dictionary` says whether `key` is one of the keys in the dictionary. So we can do this:

```
new = {
    id_: row
    for id_, row in new_data.items()
    if id_ not in old_data
}
updated = {
    id_: row
    for id_, row in new_data.items()
    if id_ in old_data and old_data[id_] != row
}
```

I'll put [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) here and let you sort out the rest on your own.